# clang-format: indentation of macros

Tags: c++, macros, clang-format

I am trying to apply clang-format to an existing code base and came across the following issue:

Simplified (and formatted) sample code:

```
#define QUERY_BEGIN()
#define QUERY_NORESULT()
#define QUERY_END()

void foo()
{
   int a = 0;

   QUERY_BEGIN()
      a = 1;
      QUERY_NORESULT()
      a = 2;
   QUERY_END()
}
```

I set the following options:

```
MacroBlockEnd:   'QUERY_END'
MacroBlockBegin: 'QUERY_BEGIN'
```

What I want to achieve is the following formatting of the macro part:

```
   QUERY_BEGIN()
      a = 1;
   QUERY_NORESULT()
      a = 2;
   QUERY_END()
```

My first guess was to set `QUERY_NORESULT` as `MacroBlockEnd` and `MacroBlockBegin` but that didn't help. It results in the following formatting:

```
   QUERY_BEGIN()
      a = 1;
      QUERY_NORESULT
         a = 2;
      QUERY_END()
```

Is there currently a way to achieve the indentation as shown above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Bad news: Sorry, this is not available in the current release version of clang-format(7).
- Good news: There is a `StatementMacros` option, which is available since clang-format 8(not release yet, but you can build from source).

See [this commit](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/commit/c59e1fef138b0ad6abda3b6b3160429b288ddae1):

> Summary:
>   Some macros are used in the body of function, and actually contain the trailing semicolon: they should thus be automatically followed by a new line, and not get merged with the next line. This is for example the case with Qt's Q_UNUSED macro:
>
> ```
>   void foo(int a, int b) {
>     Q_UNUSED(a)
>     return b;
>   }
> ```
>
> This patch deals with these cases by introducing a new option to specify list of statement macros. This re-uses the system already in place for foreach macros, to ensure there is no impact on performance.

[Document:](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/structclang_1_1format_1_1FormatStyle.html#acaf853d01318db5e3c97dfc0f3bc3481)

> ◆ StatementMacros
>
> std::vector clang::format::FormatStyle::StatementMacros
>   A vector of macros that should be interpreted as complete statements.
>
> Typical macros are expressions, and require a semi-colon to be added; sometimes this is not the case, and this allows to make clang-format aware of such cases.
>
> For example: Q_UNUSED
>
> Definition at line 1061 of file Format.h.
>
> Referenced by clang::format::FormatTokenLexer::FormatTokenLexer(), clang::format::getLLVMStyle(), llvm::yaml::MappingTraits< FormatStyle >::mapping(), and operator==().

#### Solution:

[build clang from source](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/)/wait for llvm/clang8 release, then 
put `StatementMacros ['QUERY_BEGIN()', 'QUERY_NORESULT()', 'QUERY_END()']` into your `.clang-format`.

#### [Workaround for old clang-format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#disabling-formatting-on-a-piece-of-code)

```
// clang-format off
    void    unformatted_code  ;
// clang-format on
```

Turn off clang-format in this macro statements.

Comment: The documentation cited seems to suggest the "StatementMacros" setting does not impact indentation, but that it avoids adding a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

clang-format 3.7 added support for this under the names `MacroBlockBegin` and `MacroBlockEnd`. These config options are weirder than the newer-style `(Attribute|Statement|If|Foreach)Macros` options (which take lists); the older-style `MacroBlock(Begin|End)` options take *regular expressions*, which means that if you have multiple begin/end macros, you must glue them together like this:

```
MacroBlockBegin: '(FIRST_MACRO|SECOND_MACRO)'
```

Anyway, for your exact input, and this .clang-format file:

```
$ cat .clang-format 
---
Language: Cpp
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
MacroBlockBegin: 'QUERY_BEGIN'
MacroBlockEnd: 'QUERY_END'
...
```

clang-format 14.0.6 produces this formatted output:

```
#define QUERY_BEGIN()
#define QUERY_NORESULT()
#define QUERY_END()

void foo() {
  int a = 0;

  QUERY_BEGIN()
    a = 1;
    QUERY_NORESULT()
    a = 2;
  QUERY_END()
}
```